# Why does the distribution of entropy in a deck of shuffled cards not follow a normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random, entropy, card-games

Around a year ago I did a study on shuffling cards and came across an unexpected result. I was investigating methods for quantifying how "shuffled" a deck of cards was, such as measuring the number of rising sequences in the deck or the bits of entropy of the deck.

Firstly I performed a perfectly random shuffle on a deck of cards using the Fischer-Yates method. This shuffle results in all permutations of the deck being equally likely to
occur. Imagine you have a deck of sorted cards. One by one randomly pick cards from this deck and add them to a pile, slowly forming a new deck. Once this is finished you have a perfectly randomized deck.

Then to measure how "shuffled" this deck was I used several different measurements, of which I'll highlight 2. First, labeling cards $1-52$, a rising sequence is any case where the values of these cards continue to increase by a value of $1$ as you progress
through the deck. For example, $12345678$ only has one rising sequence, while $12364578$ has two and $13254687$ has four.

Second, I calculated the entropy of the deck. To calculate this first assign cards in the deck numbers $1-52$. Say $k[x]$ gives the value of a card in the shuffled deck at position $x$. Say $d[i] = k[i+1] – k[i]$. Find all values of $d[i]$ for $0 <= i <= 52$ (for $52$ calculate the difference between $i=52$ and $i=0$). If any value of $d[i]$ is less than $0$, then add $52$ to bring it back into the positive range. Now you should have a list of $52$ difference values between $1$ and $51$. Take these values and create a normalized histogram of them (by dividing the frequency of each difference by $52$). Using these histogram values, calculate the Shannon entropy using the formula:$$E = \sum_{k=1}^{52} -p_k\log_b(p_k) $$ where $p_k$ gives the normalized histogram value. This process is fairly complicated, and I ensured I correctly coded it by running many tests against online entropy calculators where I got identical results. For all my calculations I used a log base value of $2$, so I calculated bits of entropy.

Now, I coded a program to simulate all of this and calculate my number of rising sequences and entropy. I shuffled 100 million decks using the Fischer-Yates method, and for every deck I calculated the number of rising sequences and entropy. I created a distribution of these results:
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the distribution of rising sequences follows a normal distribution, but the distribution of entropy values appears random. Why does this distribution not follow a normal distribution? Is this some property of entropy, or did I make a mistake in my program? I tested my entropy code against many online calculators and got identical results, so I don't think that is a problem. I also am using double values in my code, so they should be accurate to around 15 decimal places, far more than could account for the graph above. I also ran the same test using a different shuffling algorithm (swapping random pairs of cards 250 times), and the distribution was identical.

If you'd like to read my full study results you can do that [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EoJhtHAO5iFjikkH35KDVrmmJQpXVb5q/view?usp=sharing). I can also share the code if anyone wants to pick it apart for errors.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be normal in the first place?

Comment: @ConMan because all of my other statistics followed a normal distribution. It also doesn't make sense that within a perfectly shuffled deck you're 10 times as likely to have an entropy value of 4.84 or 4.86 than 4.85. Why that particular value? What if you increased the deck size to 100, 200, or 500 cards? All just questions that I'm curious about.

Comment: At a guess, two or three things are happening - first, by taking values modulo 52 you've essentially folded some of the tails of what might be more normal-looking in on itself. Second, the complicated dependencies between potential values of $k$ in the entropy calculation is forcing a lot of quantisation into the probabilities. Third, the other things that happen to look bell-shaped are "better" at meeting the requirements for the central limit theorem in some form whereas the entropy calculation is just weird enough for it to not be apparent at this scale.

Answer (score 2):

0. **Definition**:  A sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ is said to be *asymptotically Normal* just if there exist real (nonrandom) sequences $(a_n), (b_n),$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left({X_n-a_n\over b_n} \in A \right)=\mathbb P\left(Z \in A \right)$ for any interval $A\subseteq\mathbb R$, where $Z$ is a standard Normal random variable.
1. Simulations strongly suggest that the entropies $(E_n)$ are asymptotically Normal:
   [image: distribution of entropy for various n]

   Here "standardized entropy" is just ${(E_n -\hat \mu_n)/\hat\sigma_n}$ in a sample of size $N$, with $\hat\mu_n, \hat\sigma_n$ being the sample mean and sample standard deviation (which are found to have effectively converged when $N=10^7$). The green-outlined histogram is just a standardized version of the OP's histogram.
2. Each of the three histograms shown above is effectively the limit distribution for the corresponding *fixed* value of $n$ (the number of cards). (Empirically we observe that samples of size greater than $N=10^7$ result in essentially the same histograms.) These histograms show that it's not until $n$ is well-above $100$ that the distribution of $E_n$ becomes "approximately" Normal.
3. Asymptotic Normality would be implied by a Central Limit Theorem that "almost applies" here:
   A paper by Morris[1975 ], [“Central Limit Theorems for Multinomial Sums.”](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-3/issue-1/Central-Limit-Theorems-for-Multinomial-Sums/10.1214/aos/1176343006.full), proves a CLT that would apply here *if the adjacent-card differences were i.i.d. Uniform*.  (Empirically, these differences do appear to be asymptotically Uniform$\{1,...,n-1\}$.)  Note that such a special kind of CLT is required because, in addition to the observed frequencies being mutually *dependent*, also the number of population categories ($n-1$) itself depends on $n$. (Classical results are for a *fixed number* of categories while $n\to\infty$.)
4. $E_n$ is a simple function of the well-known [Likelihood Ratio Statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) ($G_n$) for testing $H_0:\pi_1=...=\pi_k=1/k$ in Multinomial populations when $k$ depends on $n$;  e.g., if $k=n-1$, then
   $$E_n:= -\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} f_j\log_2f_j= \log_2 (n-1) - {G_n\over 2 n \ln 2}$$
   where $$G_n:=2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} N_j\ln{N_j\over n/(n-1)},\quad N_j=nf_j.$$
   It's also interesting to note a connection to [Pearson's Chi-square statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) ($X_n^2$, often used for testing goodness-of-fit):
   $$G_n\approx X_n^2 :=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}{(N_j-n/(n-1))^2\over n/(n-1)}. $$